# R: Identify non-NA values from one column and create dataframe with values from another column based rows selected

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have a data frame (df) with multiple columns (45) and rows (20,000):

[image]

I want to filter each variable column by selecting only the rows with non-NA values and creating a separate data frame with the corresponding ID and Name for the rows selected. I then want to save each data frame with the corresponding variable name. For example, the output data frames would look like this and would be saved as Var1 and Var2 respectively.

Var 1 <

[image]

Var 2 <

[image]

I am currently trying to use this function on R and thinking of implementing a for loop.

df2 = lapply(df, function(x) {x[!is.na(x)]}).

This hasn't worked so well as it does not list the values from corresponding ID and Name column. This also doesn't create a dataframe.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it can be done using `dplyr` & `purrr`

Note that next time instead of posting image of your data, please try create sample data in R and copy paste the `dput` of that sample data instead.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Name = c("D", "E", "F"),
  Var1 = c(1, NA, 2),
  Var2 = c(2, 2, NA),
  Var4 = c(NA, NA, 4))

columns <- names(data)[grepl("^Var", names(data))]


extract_na_item <- function(column_name, df) {
  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!sym(column_name))) %>%
    select(ID, Name)
}
list_var_not_na <- map(columns, extract_na_item, df = data)
names(list_var_not_na) <- columns
```

**Here is the result**

```r
list_var_not_na
#> $Var1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   ID    Name 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A     D    
#> 2 C     F    
#> 
#> $Var2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   ID    Name 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A     D    
#> 2 B     E    
#> 
#> $Var4
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   ID    Name 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 C     F
```

And if you really want to have the variable assignment in global environment as you mentioned in OP you can do as below (Though I recommend just use the list to access the data instead)

```
list2env(list_var_not_na, envir = globalenv())
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` like so :

```
cols <- grep('Var', names(df))
df2 <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) df[!is.na(x), -cols])
df2

#$Var1
#  ID Name
#1  A    D
#3  C    F

#$Var2
#  ID Name
#1  A    D
#2  B    E

#$Var4
#  ID Name
#3  C    F
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Name = c("D", "E", "F"), 
    Var1 = c(1, NA, 2), Var2 = c(2, 2, NA), Var4 = c(NA, NA, 
    4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```